# Javascript calculation - onchange is null? wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

My form calculations work in my jsfiddle, however in my wordpress page, it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null`.  Is my page not loading the function when it loads?

(javascript in the header)

```
function doTotal(form) {
    var a = (+form.halfday1.value);
    var b = (+form.fullday1.value);


    form.total1.value = a + b ;
}
document.getElementById("quote").onchange = function (){doTotal(this)};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2666c/

Comment: The page is loading the function fine, but it seems that your script cannot find the element `#quote`. Where are you including the JS inside your WordPress install?

Comment: I am using a plugin "HTML Javascript Adder" to include the JS into wordpress

Comment: Do you have a live demo?

Comment: I can perhaps pm you the link to the page? if possible?

Comment: @BenM Or can I post the link here?

Comment: Yes, post a link here.

Comment: `403 Forbidden` error.

Comment: sorry, i think it is correct now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code not run, becouse on moment it try to find the `<element id="quote"/>` there are no such elements. You need to put your code under this element. Or run it on [document load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery) event.
As example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('#quote').change(function (){doTotal(this)});
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Arthur Halma, however it is now giving a difference msg in the console? `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < `

Comment: Console must say the line number of the error part. Can you show this line to me?

Comment: sure.  `<body onload="document.getElementById('quote').onchange = function (){doTotal(this)};"/>`

Comment: and what `<body onload="alert('1');" />` says in this case?

Comment: `<body onload="alert('1');" />` shows "as is" in the console, and is not included in the error lines

Comment: What you mean "as is"? Did you recived alert popup with text "1" inside?

Comment: sorry, no. i can just see that line inside the coding.  there was no popup

Comment: So there is some another error such as not closed tags and so. Try to put `document.getElementById("quote").onchange = function (){doTotal(this)};` under your form (after `</form>`). But anyway looks like you have some scripts or markup problems in other place.

Comment: Can you provide me with link to your webpage?

Comment: `403: Forbidden`. Dod you have some IP filters on your host enabladed or something?

Comment: yes, now that I think of it, I think so. How can I enable you to view the page?

Comment: Looks like this page protected to moderators only, can you make it publick?

Comment: it says it is public. how about if i add a password.. might work: password:  123

Comment: Webpage oppened. I see you have jQuery libriary. So you can use `jQuery(document).ready()`, check my updated answer. Delete all I provide to you before and replace it with code from my answer.

Comment: Thank you kindly for taking the time to assist me :) I appreciate it greatly. My form is now calculating correctly

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to protect your webpage (or change your password to new one).

Comment: Is there perhaps a way that I can use this same calculation for 2nd section of these fields (ie "(+form.halfday2.value);" and "(+form.fullday2.value);") without copying the code over and over and changing the field names? :)

Comment: I think you need to open new question for this (with some sample code to preview).